# Is it necessary to use Poisson - Boltzmann equation if I only need to build electrostatic potential from a PQR file?

Tags: poisson, electromagnetism, computational-biology

A PQR file of a protein describes the positions in $x$, $y$ and $z$ and the charges of every atom in it. If you have them, you can construct the charge density $\rho(x)$ of the protein, then use it to find the potential $\phi(x)$. The Boltzmann distribution is useful when you can't or don't know how to build the $\rho(x)$.

So is it necessary to use Poisson - Boltzmann equation if I only need to build electrostatic potential from a PQR file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So Is it neccesary to use Poisson - Boltzmann equation if I only need to build electrostatic potential from a PQR file?

No. You can use Poisson.

Since you know the positions of each point charge, you know the charge distribution $\rho$, which is a sum of delta functions.

You can thus solve numerically the Poisson's equation that links the charge distribution to the laplacian of the potential:

$
\begin{equation}
\Delta V=\rho
\end{equation}$

The solution will depend upon your boundary conditions.
Also, many algorithms are available to find this solution.

One example may be found [here on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0605371). This paper is called "Efficient solution of Poisson's equation with free boundary conditions".